# AJAX not mating up with Codeigniter Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am learning AJAX and have borrowed a script from NETTUTS Codeigniter from Scratch: AJAX
The script itself works perfectly as adapted to my form, however it is not updating the database per the controller.  Firebug says the post went fine from the AJAX script. I guess my question is, how and where am I failing to start the controller?

The form_open script

```
echo form_open('contacts/entry', $form);
```

Ajax script(there is validation script above what I am showing that works fine)

```
 var form_data = {
    fname: $('#fname').val(),
    lname: $('#lname').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    phone: $('#phone').val(),
    relate: $('#relate').val(),
    ajax: '1'
};

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('contacts/entry'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'form_data',
    success: function() {
        $('#status').text('Update successful!'); 
    }
});

return false;
```

});

Note that I have included "AJAX: 1" in the form_data
The controller

```
function entry()
{
   if ($this->input->post('ajax')) {  
   $data = array
           (
           'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
           'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
           'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
           'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
           'relate' => $this->input->post('relate'),
           );

   //removed validation set rules to shorten the question

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
   {
    $this->db->insert('contacts', $data);   
    $this->index();    
   } else
   {
    $this->index();
   }       
} 
}
```

Is the use of "if ($this->input->post('ajax'))" the right way to initiate the controller? Without the jquery the form works fine by itself and does run the controller.  So I know the two individual pieces work, they just are not meshing.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I'll delete the `var form_data { ajax: '1' }` and use something like this:

```
if($this->input->server('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest')
{
    // This is AJAX
}
else {
    // This is standard HTTP
}
```

A nice way to handle this if is to use a MY_Controller. If you use it, add a function like this:

```
protected function is_ajax() {
    return ($this->input->server('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest') ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

And you can use:

```
if($this->is_ajax())
{
    // This is AJAX
}
else {
    // This is HTTP
}
```

Then you've to echo the results to pass it to the actual view and handle the operation. Like this:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
{
    // Tip: you've to do the data management on MODELS
    $action = $this->db->insert('contacts', $data);

    // With this method you can handle AJAX and HTTP on the same
    // validation. If is AJAX you print, if not you redirect.
    if($this->is_ajax())
        echo $action;
    else {
        // if worked, redirect the user to the success 
        // else send it to the form error
        if($action)
            redirect("form_success");
        else
            redirect("form_error");
    }
else {
    if($this->is_ajax())
        echo false;
    else {
        $this->load->view("error_form");
    }
}
```

And you've to correct you jQuery code to handle the operation:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('contacts/entry'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data, // Like said jondavidjohn
    success: function(data) {
        if(data)
        {
            $('#status').text('Update successful!');
        } else {
            $('#status').text('Operation failed!');
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah, so basically everything I suggested + check for the XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: and checking if(data === true) is redundant, by default it checks if it is true.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: thank you! i edit it! :) I added some come to handle the ajax and http in the same function too.

Comment: When you upgrade to CI 2.0 you can use $this->input->is_ajax_request();

Answer (score 2):

you're posting the string `'form_data'` instead of the variable `form_data` , remove the quotes around form_data and try again.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('contacts/entry'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,    // <-- previously you had data: 'form_data', which would pass the string 'form_data', not the variable.
    success: function() {
        $('#status').text('Update successful!'); 
    }
});
```

I would also echo the result of your db operation and then use the returned data to test if the db operation completed successfull.

php/CI

```
...
echo $this->db->insert('contacts',$data);
...
```

jQuery/AJAX

```
...
success: function(data) {
    if(data) {
        //alert success
    }
    else {
        //alert failure
    }
}
```

Comment: I just added the quotes, it didnt work with them or before them. This is a list of personal contacts and I have the database output right below the form. Without the jquery the insert works fine.  I also review the database in phpmyadmin.  But I will give what you suggest a try.  I do get the "Update successful!" indication

Comment: you mean removed the quotes? I'll update my answer with exactly how your ajax call should look.

Comment: It still tells me the call was successful, except that I am not initiating the controller to do the insert as it should.

Comment: what does it actually tell you about the controller?  before you insert, in your controller, print_r($data); it should print out exactly what is contained in $data so you will know if the info is getting passed properly.

Comment: Show us the exact error. Without them we can't see what is happening.

Comment: Thats the problem, I do not get an error.  When I submit, the AJAX tells me that it was successful.  Nothing I add to the controller does anything, such as adding print_r($data); Let me remove the AJAX: '1'

Comment: Ok, I solved it.  the whole thing was the { ajax: '1' } and requiring it in the controller.  Thank you very much all of you and thanks for asking me to remove it.  Isem I will take your suggestions and study them

Comment: @Bard: my answer was the one suggesting to remove the **ajax**... By the way, @jondavidjhon answer was good! :)

Comment: Ok, you are correct and I will change the checkmark. TY.  BTW, would you also use serialize in this case?

Comment: ajax: 1 or not, you were just passing 'form_data' as a string from the start, so even if you took out the ajax:1 it still would not work...

Comment: true Johndavid, but I had just put the 'form_data' in prior to copying it to SO. It did not work either way.  Originally I did not have the quotes in the script.  I wish I could mark both of you with the answer becuase you are both great